# How to filter mongodb result for datatables?

Tags: php, mongodb, datatables

I use this script to get the collection of my mongo database: http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mongodb

My question is: how to retrieve the rows where `foo == 'mystring'` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will notice (on line 29) from the source code in the file the mongo collection has been given the name: `$m_collection` as such:

```
$m_collection->find(array('foo' => 'mystring'))
```

Should work.

If this is not what you are looking for maybe you can be more specific and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

#### UPDATE

It has come to my attention you might want to instead edit the `$searchTermsAll` variable to search by this field in a doc. By the looks of it this PHP class links in the same as it would normally for SQL as such you should need to do anyhting special and can just enable filtering on datatables and add the value `mystring` to the `foo` field.

However to know if it is the right answer you will need to clarify.

#### UPDATE 2

A more destructive way of doing this that should keep filtering is to replace line 99 with:

```
$cursor = $m_collection->find(array_merge($searchTerms, 
    array('foo' => 'mystring')), $fields);
```

That will always make sure that your condition is added to the search terms but keeps the users own search terms.

Comment: Hi Sammaye and thanks for reply, this <code>$m_collection->find(array('foo' => 'mystring'));</code> work fine. BUT, now I can't filter the result on my table. I need to force the rows returned to contains 'mystring' and after I need to filter on the datatables upon request (maybe keeping the variable $searchTerms) ?

Comment: @user1770562 Yea I think datatables has a built in default setting so you default it filter on that but allow all other columns to filter correctly, let me look in the docs

Comment: @user1770562 hmm you could run `fnFilter` in your JS but that will filter all columns. I think the best way is to code it in such a manner that the data that goes into the table initially is filtered. Do you use this php file to also fill the table on load of the page or do you provide your own data?

Comment: yes Sammaye, it's possible to use api filtering on datables with fnFilter() ... but it means that I have to recover all rows and filter after :( I have 1 million row, it's less performance I think. AND it's just a table for reading data. thanks

Comment: @panpansh I added a possible server side solution where you can hack the file directly to merge your condition with the search terms variable so you can keep the users defined one but add your own bit on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("foo" => "mystring"));
```

Here is more details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

Comment: Thanks GBD, I answered to Sammaye. Thanks you too. I need to keep $searchTerms I think for custom filtering on datatables by the user.